# read json data from a request nodejs

Tags: node.js, request

im trying to read json data and get the price of ETC. The problem is that the path to get the price in usd has a "-" in the ethereum-classic name and im getting errors.

```
        url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum-classic&vs_currencies=usd";


        request(url, (err, res, body) => {


            const data = JSON.parse(body);
            const item = data.ethereum-classic.usd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this ?

```
const item = data["ethereum-classic"].usd
```